# .NET MVC HTML.TextBox is hugely out of proportion on the screen

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

As the title suggests I am using .NET MVC's 'html.textboxfor' razor commands.

For some reason my css classes as causing these input fields to be vastly disproportioned to their original static counterparts.

The screenshot below only has the title section with an input box, which seems to be correctly sized:

[image: Only title section with html.textboxfor]

But as soon as I make the price sections editable this happens:

[image: All sections html.textboxfor]

This is the html table (located in a loop) that I am using to generate the HTML:

```
<table width="1%">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title[outer], new { @class = "title", @Value="Title"})
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title[outer], new { @class = "rands", @Value = "99" })

    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title[outer], new { @class = "cents", @Value = "Title" })


                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="units">each</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

These are the CSS classes:

```
.title {
font-size: 6vh;
margin-top: 2vh;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
top: 4vh;
width: 100%;
}

.rands{
font-size:25vh;
font-weight:700;
margin:0px !important;
}

.cents {
    bottom: 14vh;
    font-size: 12vh;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: 15vw;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `vh` units for your font-size. This is more or less a percentage equivalent to the height of your current viewport hence the hugeness.

There are lots of ways you can size your fonts in css but I'd personally go with something like:

```
html {
   font-size: 10px;
}

.title {
   font-size: 2rem;
   ...
}

.rands{
   font-size: 3rem;
   ...
}

.cents {
    font-size: 2rem;
    ...
}
```

`rem` sets the font size based on the base (`html` element) pixel font size so you can scale nice and quickly.

I'd recommend you read more on font-size and `px`, `em`, `rem`